# Update single row in table based on joined selection and return the id of the row updated

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to update the first row that matches a criteria in table based on a join to another table, and also return the id of the row updated.

Simplified versions of the tables are as follows

table1

| id | date | site | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-12 | a | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-06-12 | a | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-06-12 | b | 1 |

table2

| id | start | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-12 | 1 |
| 2 | null | 0 |
| 3 | null | 0 |

To select the new row I can use this

```
SELECT id FROM
  table2 JOIN table1 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE
  table1.active = 1
AND table1.site = "b"
AND table2.start IS NULL
```

This would return 3. I'd like a command that will update table2.start with NOW() that matches the SELECT above and also return the id of the row updated. Is that possible in a single statement?

Update statement below. It may not be the most efficient but it's where I ended up.

```
UPDATE table2 as t2
  INNER JOIN
(SELECT id FROM table1
  JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE
  table1.active = 1
AND table1.site = "b"
AND table2.start IS NULL
ORDER BY table1.id
LIMIT 1) as t2 ON t1.load_id = t2.load_id
  
SET t1.start = CASE
  WHEN t1.start IS NULL THEN NOW()
  ELSE t1.start = t1.start
END
```

Comment: Update example provided. Thank you

Comment: I refer you again to my previous comment